# MVC/Jquery sending AJAX response into a view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a grid that displays a list of projects.  Each row has a checkbox with each project's associated ID.  I'm trying to pass an array of each selected checkbox's value into my controller, get a list of those projects' data, and then on the response pass that data into a view that displays a list of all of that project data.  It's getting all the way back to the response, but I can't figure out how to get the model, which is bound to the display view, to accept the response.

Here's what I have:

The jQuery call:

```
$("#PrintProjectFormId").submit(function (event) {

    var selectedProjects = [];
    selectedProjects = projectsGrid.$('input[type="checkbox"]').serializeArray();

    var projects = [];
    $(selectedProjects).each(function (i, field) {
        projects.push(field.value);
    });

    var action = $("#PrintProjectFormId").attr("action");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: {
            projectId: projects
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#printProjectModal").modal('hide');

            //wait for modal to close before redirect
            $("#printProjectModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {

                window.location = result.Url + "/" + result.responseData;

            });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("There was a problem submitting this project to print.");
        }
        });
    });
```

The controller action:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult GetPrintableProject(Guid[] projectId)
  {
   var message = "";
   var vmOneSheet = _projectService.MassExport(projectId);

 message = "Projectsreturned";
 UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("ProjectExport", "Project");
        return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl, response = message, responseData = vmOneSheet });
    }
```

which calls:

```
    public ActionResult ProjectPDFExport(IEnumerable<ProjectExportVM> vmOneSheet)
    {
        return View("ProjectPDFExport", vmOneSheet);
    }
```

and the display view:

```
@using Web.ViewModels
@model IEnumerable<ProjectExportVM>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
//displays each project
```

The response data is an inumerable list of viewmodels, one for each project selected in the original grid.

I have it working fine as long as it's just an ActionResult, but we're trying to make this an AJAX call.  Think I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: What is the return value of responseData?

Comment: The response data is an inumerable list of viewmodels, one for each project selected in the original grid.  I added it to the question

Comment: if you're going to do a `window.location` (which of course will navigate to a new page) immediately after you return from the AJAX call, then there's no point in using AJAX. The whole point of AJAX is to _stay on the same page_. If you want the server-side razor code to build the HTML for your view based on the response data then just do a normal form submit and then return the view normally in the action method. That way you save yourself a pointless extra HTTP request and a lot of useless extra JavaScript code.

Comment: Right, I'm starting to get that.  This might sound really noob, but the reason I've been asked to convert this to an AJAX call is so that we can display some kind of loading indicator to the user while the call is running and I was having trouble finding a way to make that call from the view without using AJAX.  The more I've researched this, it's become apparent that I'm going way out of my way for something that should be simple.

Comment: However if you want to use AJAX and stay within your existing view, then you could either a) have the server return a Partial View (which will be some HTML rendered by Razor code, like a normal view but without all the `<head><body>` periphery of a full view) and then use JS to append that HTML to a suitable place in your existing HTML, or b) do as you do now and return JSON, and then write some JavaScript to process that data, create some HTML (perhaps using a client-side templating plugin) and display the data however you are wanting to within the existing view

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this, before you pass the result on your AJAX return, serialize it first using Newtonsoft JSON serializer:

```
return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl, response = message, 
                  responseData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vmOneSheet) });
```

After serializing, get it on the ActionResult, using as string as your parameter, then from there, deserialize it:

```
public ActionResult ProjectPDFExport(string vmOneSheet)
{
   var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ProjectExportVM>>(vmOneSheet);  
   //You will get the result as IEnumerable of ProjectExportVM  
}
```

No need to change code on both views.